# RSS feed not validating on Wordpress integration

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I have integrated WP to my website and have issues with RSS feed.

This is the blog page:

[soeezauto.ma](http://soeezauto.ma/soeez-blog)

The validation at feedvalidator.org gives the following error:

```
line 187, column 0: XML parsing error: <unknown>:187:0: junk after document element [help]
```

Looking at the validation result, the 'junk' is what one would see as 'page source' at Firefox's  web developer tool.

I am including a link to the validation result, hope it works.

[feedvalidator.org of soeezauto.ma](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsoeezauto.ma%2Fsoeez-blog%2Ffeed%2F)

So, it outputs the feed just fine and then continues on to output the 'page source' of the blog page. For some reason it does not stop at the closing `</rss>` tag.

You can check the feed  here:

[soeez-blog](http://soeezauto.ma/soeez-blog/feed/)

It looks fine but, again, if you check the 'page source' from the above link you will see the 'junk' after the regular feed XML code.

I tried the 'regular' steps like deactivating all plugins, but still getting the error. Some other posts indicate issues with blank spaces, but I could not find any in the few files from WP I am using or that I have changed.

Thanks

Comment: That link doesn't look fine to me, looks completely blank.

Comment: Sorry ohgodwhy, I made a bit of a mess with the links, god knows why, if you allow me a bit of a pun. Should be fine now.

Comment: The primary page looks fine, but the RSS feed is still blank. in `wp-config.php` find `DEFINE('WP_DEBUG', false);` and change that to `true`.

Comment: OK, did that, but I have not seen anything special afterwards. Also, what do you mean the RSS is blank. If you go to the link above you will see a RSS feed page and it is not blank at all.